# Detect when fire of local notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, localnotification

There is a way to detect when a `localnotification` is fire??
For example i have one notification that is fire 12:00 a.m it show the `notification` there is way to know if the user touch the `notification`.
Because if the user no touch the `notification` i want to set other alarm to fire at 20 minutes after if it not touch the `notification` when is fire.

Answer (score 2):

Call `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` in the app delegate to know when the user returns to the app from a notification. Note: this is only called if the application was not closed, i.e. closed via multi-tasking. I'd suggest setting a timer for 12:00AM to set another notifcation and if the user returns to the application from the first notification then cancel the second one.

Comment: Exactly, set 2 local notifications, first at the desired date and the second one at the date of the first one + 20 minutes (or whatever interval you want).  Then if the first one fires, cancel the second one. If it doesn't fire, the 2nd one will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

while application in forground or background then this method call when fire notification in appDelgate

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{

}
```

if application close then click on notification then didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method check is local notification

```
if ([[launchOptions allKeys] UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey]) {


    }
```